# How to load contacts in text view at the time of editing?

Tags: android, contacts

Hi
I am creating a contact based application.In that i have a text view in that I want load the contacts from phone at the time of editing the text view.

Please any one help me how to do this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Also, bear in mind that the quality of the support you get is tied to the quality of your question, and your question does not make much sense.

Comment: You should try out these first http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-querying-data-from-your-phone-book-names-addresses-postcodes-emails-etc/ then look into how to load it to a simple adapter list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to get notified when the editing starts.
For more information on how to query contacts you can take a look at the contacts tutorial provided at http://blog.app-solut.com/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-adroid/
its about how to query all contacts and basic information on contacts.